# How to display users chances " % " depending on their bet amounts?

Tags: javascript, probability

I'm developing a Jackpot Roulette game. There is a main pot. Users join each round. Every bet is going to the main pot. And the winner will get the pot.

I'm looking for a way to display to each user their chance to win in each moment. (I can update that chance every 1 second, to keep him updated).

I have an array of users, every user did a bet amount.

For example:

```
[ username: user1, betAmount: 600], 
[ username: user2, betAmount: 400]
```

and so on..

How can I calculate their chance to win?

In this array for example, I will like to show to user1 his chance is for example 60%, and user2 40%.

I don't know how to calculate, their chance, and display to them.

I'm looking for a function that can calculate their chance, depending on the bet amounts them did compared with other users. Max chance is 100% and will be divided by the users at that moment.

Comment: What do you mean by "win"? What is the criteria?

Comment: `I dont know how to calculate, their chance` - well, that's a problem, how would you calculate their chance if this were not a program? because there's absolutely no information in your question on how **you** wish to calculate the chance, so are we supposed to read your mind?

Comment: Also, how are you calculating the "win" ? Wouldn't you want a formula like `(userBet/totalBet) * 100` to get their chance of winning??

Comment: I just edited the post a bit guys. I know the basics of javascript, and a bit more, but im just bad at math. Im looking for a function that can calculate every user in the array chance, max chance is 100% but that 100% will be divided into the users.lenght of the array. So every user will have a different chance, depending on their bet amount.

Comment: `For example, user2 has 60% chance to win, and user1 40%` how do you get from bet 100 and 300 to chance 40 and 60? - I would think with bet 100 and 300 ... the chance would be 25 and 75 - again, can't read your mind as to how you calculate chance from bet

Comment: _"max chance will be 100% ) But that 100% will be divided in the amount of users are playing that round."_ How is that possible? A player makes 100% of the "bet amount" though they still do not have 100% chance to "win"?

Comment: Yes u are right, was just a bad example. MY head just hurt atm, im looking for someone to helps me a bit. Sorry is my first post there bdw.

Comment: @guest271314 if a player makes 100% of bets, there's no other players

Comment: @Derek's formula looks about right

Comment: If a player is alone in that round, and any one didnt joined yet ( Him has 100% chance to win ) If someone else joins that round, the 100% chance is divided by that 2 users.

Comment: @JaromandaX How do we know what 100% is?

Comment: Yeah i think derek is right. Im looking for something like that. I need a way to calculate all the users bet, and convert them into a ("%") chance. So everyone can know how much is their chance to win the pot at that moment.

Comment: @HannatheNewbyDeveloper Is the only criteria to "win" the amount of "bet amount" that they make? If that is the case there is no need for a percentage at all. The user which provides the greatest "bet amount" is automatic "win", and so forth. The calculation is linear and finite  1., 2., 3.

Comment: @guest271314 yes usually big bet will win, but i included a bit of randomize, the winner is choosed by a npm library. I just looking for a way to display the chance to the user every moment him post a bet or update his bet.

Comment: I don't think so-OP states the bet amount as part of the total drives the probability of winning. Seems like simple math.

Comment: _"but i included a bit of randomize"_ Then you would be supplying false data if you are calculating odds of "win" on "bet amount" alone.

Comment: @guest271314 - 100% is probability of 1 - so, every "game" has a winner

Comment: @JaromandaX _"but i included a bit of randomize"_ What if "randomize" does not select only "player"? Is "randomize" algorithm not applicable if there is only one "player"? For example, if algorithm was 1 or 0 for 1 "player" and 0 is selected, where "player" is 1. Does the house "win"? fwiw, gracious effort helping at Answer nonetheless.

Comment: The library what im using, is requested me for a chance to win, like chance: 50, chance 40, chance 10... A user with 10% chance can win too, but usually bigger chance will win always.

Comment: @guest271314 - there's no indication that the house ever wins - hence why the total chances for the players chances is 100% if you get my meaning ... or total probability that any player wins is 1 - that's what I interpreted "100%" to mean - however, I do see your point having read the question again after reading your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example of how you'd calculate the odds based on `betAmount/total(betAmounts)*100`

```js
var bets = [
  { username: 'user1', betAmount: 100 }, 
  { username: 'user2', betAmount: 300 }
];
// get the total bets
var totalbets = bets.map(({betAmount}) => betAmount).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
// output (to console)
bets.forEach(({username, betAmount}) => {
  console.log(`user ${username} odds ${betAmount/totalbets*100}`);
});
```

How to display it on a web page depends on the page, you've supplied no HTML to work with.

A little explanation of the code:

[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array using the results of calling the provided function for each element in the original array. In this case the result of .map is an array of numbers `[100, 300]`.

[Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) applies the given function against a "accumulator" with the end result being a single value. In this case the function is called a single time with `a = 100` and `b = 300`, the result is the returned value `a + b = 400`.

If there were three values in the array, say `[3,2,1]`:

- First call a=3,b=2, returns a+b = 5
- Second call a=5 (the returned value from previous iteration), b=1 - the result is a+b=6

Read the linked documentation for each for better explanation, as reduce for example can also be supplied an initial value for the accumulator, which would mean for an array of 3 values, the callback function is called 3 times, not 2.

Comment: Hey thanks you a lot for the fast reply. I think this one will help me a lot. I will try it right now, but looks like this is all what i need. Thanks for your time Jaromanda.

Comment: Thanks again, it solved my trouble. Is there a way to comment u or reward u in some way?

Comment: Is it worth briefly explaining map/reduce, Jaromanda? That's a complex set of topics for a beginner (personally I'd avoid it for this reason - a loop might be less elegant, but it is much more understandable).

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends.... What game are the people playing? Based on what game they are playing then that would decide if bet amount is a factor in their chance to win.

Instead of using bet amounts try using whatever value they bet on and then compare that value to a possible amount of values.

For example if the rules of the game is choose a number from 1-100 and the more your bet amount the more numbers you can choose, then you can calculate their chance to win as the `number of values they chose / 100`. So if I bet 200 and chose numbers 10 and 3, and you bet 100 and chose the number 61, I have a 2% chance to win and you have a 1% chance to win.

However if you want to use bet amounts as a factor then do this:

```
var bettotal = bet1 + bet2 + bet3 + bet4;
var user1chance = bet1 / bettotal * 100;
//etc etc...
```

And then if you want to display it to an element:

```
document.findElementById('myID').value = user1chance;
```

Comment: Is a JackpotGame. There is a POT, and every user bet is added to the pot. I need to display every user chance, depending on the bet they did. How i could approach this situation?

Comment: @HannatheNewbyDeveloper I edited my answer look at the code at the bottom of my post

Comment: Thanks for ur reply Josh, and the time u spend. Thanks a lot, have a good day / night.

Comment: @HannatheNewbyDeveloper no prob

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a given user's chance to win is bet amount divided by total amount bet (×100%).  So if user 1 bets 100, user 2 300, then user 1 has a 25% chance to win (100 / 400)